# Is angular routing template url support for partial view (.cshtml) file in ASP.Net MVC 4 Project?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is angular routing template url support for .cshtml file in ASP.Net MVC 4 Project ?

because when I use html page or .aspx page it load that page but when I use .cshtml page it is not loading the view.

Actually I want to load partial view with angular where no action method is there for that partial view.

Is it possible with Angular Routing ?

Comment: You need a controller to load the `.cshtml` page, so you need to hit something like `/Home/Index` to load up that `.cshtml` page!

Comment: Is there no way other than this if I don't want to create controller ??

Comment: Not that I know of. Its the pattern that MVC follows right, so a request comes in, it gets routed to a controller, that then executes some code and returns the view.

Answer (score 0):

I have my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I set up my routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "SPA",
        url: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

I create my `Index.cshtml`:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
</head>
<body>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularsrc")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularapp")
</body>
</html>
```

Then when I hit my site through the debug the url will look like this:

```
localhost:5623/
```

This URL will load up my default controller with my default action. The default action will load up my `Index.cshtml`. The index page will load up all my angular files and angular app.

So this means you can use ASP.NET MVC bundling system to create the angular bundles.